# Howto get ajax loaded data when ripping a webpage

Tags: ajax, asp-classic, serverxmlhttp

I am currently using this function in a classic asp page to get the content of a web page, extract some data and display it.

```
Function GetHTML(strURL)
Dim objXMLHTTP
Set objXMLHTTP = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
objXMLHTTP.Open "GET", strURL, False
objXMLHTTP.Send
GetHTML = objXMLHTTP.responseText
Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing
End Function
```

Unfortunately, since more and more websites are using ajax to load data into the divs after the standard HTML has been loaded, my function does not get the data from these divs.

How can I get the complete page in my string?

Comment: your code looks ok, but it's impossible to tell you whats wrong when we don't have all of the details. what's "not" working? are you getting any errors? have you written objXMLHTTP.responseText out to the screen and it came up blank? what kind of page are you calling? any errors showing in your dev console?

Comment: "my function does not get the data from these divs" - once you call a page via ajax, you're simply getting the rendered content that the server spits out, you will not be able easily get any data loaded via JS

Comment: You will need a more fully-functional scraping technique: one which runs included scripts and downloads linked or dynamic content and renders it. A "headless" component like Selenium might do it, depending on your exact needs.

Comment: Example page:https://jouw.postnl.nl/?pst=sp-pnl-nav-ontv-ql1-tracktrace#!/track-en-trace/zoeken

Comment: If you 'View Source' in IE11 (or Chrome, or FireFox) you will not see the content of several divs. Just like when using the XMLHTTP component.

Comment: If you go to the DOM explorer (IE11) you can see the actual data.

Comment: So, I need a component that gets the inital page frame and then executes all code and after the page is fully loaded returns the complete page data. All common browsers have this functionality otherwise they would not be able to display all content. Is it maybe possible to use a browser component to get the required result? Anyone done that before?